# Why PHP foreach on DOMDocument elements happens every 2 of them?

Tags: php

Why foreach loop over DOMDocument elements happens every 2 nodes?

I mean It cuts and pastes nodes 1, 3, 5 etc. forgetting to do so with 2, 4, 6 yet `$dom_body_scripts->length` returns `int(6)`

Code:

```
// Prepare DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($buffer);
$dom->formatOutput = true;

// hook <head>
$dom_head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);

// hook <body>
$dom_body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

// <script> tags in <body>
$dom_body_scripts = $dom_body->getElementsByTagName('script'); 

// cut each <script> tag from <body> and append it to <head>
foreach ($dom_body_scripts as $script) {
    if ($script->getAttribute('type') === 'text/javascript') {
        $dom_head->appendChild($script);
    }
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
```

Sample HTML input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample HTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show an example of the HTML you're working with that gives you that behavior so we can see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: Input and output: http://pastebin.com/t6tjx8eS

Comment: It may something to do with DOM* placing all scripts in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `$dom_body_scripts` is not an array list that's why you can't iterate with all the found results.

In order to do so I have a for that based on the result of `$dom_body_scripts` will get all the `script` within `$dom_body`:

```
<?php
$str = <<<DATA
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test0.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
DATA;

// Prepare DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$dom->formatOutput = true;

// hook <head>
$dom_head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
// hook <body>
$dom_body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
// <script> tags in <body>
$dom_body_scripts = $dom_body->getElementsByTagName('script'); 

// cut each <script> tag from <body> and append it to <head>
for($i = $dom_body_scripts->length; $i > 0; $i--)
{
    $script = $dom_body->getElementsByTagName('script')->item($i - 1);
    if ($script->getAttribute('type') === 'text/javascript')
    {
        $dom_head->appendChild($script);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/116133)